# Creating Tables and seeing this error - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE Office(
       Office_ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
       Phone_Number CHAR(11) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT Office_PK PRIMARY KEY (Office_ID));
CREATE TABLE Faculty(
       Faculty_ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
       First_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
       Last_Name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
       Office_ID INT NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT Faculty_PK PRIMARY KEY (Faculty_ID) 
            CONSTRAINT Faculty_FK FOREIGN KEY (Office_ID) REFERENCES Office(Office_ID));
CREATE TABLE Student(
       Student_ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
       First_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
       Last_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
       Phone_Number CHAR(11) NOT NULL,
       Sposue_Name VARCHAR (30),
       Street_Address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
       City VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
       State CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
       Zip VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
       Advisor_ID INT NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT Student_PK PRIMARY KEY (Student_ID) 
            CONSTRAINT Student_FK FOREIGN KEY (Advisor_ID) REFERENCES Faculty(Faculty_ID));
```

Can someone help me understand what I'm missing? I don't understand where the error is coming from.

Comment: Constraints are attributes of a table and need to be separated by commas, just like columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not e.g.

```
Office_ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
```

but

```
Office_ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
```

(`not null` comes last).

---

Also, you miss comma at the end of `CONSTRAINT` statements in the last two tables.

Once you fix that, it works OK.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Office(
  2         Office_ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL ,
  3         Phone_Number CHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  4              CONSTRAINT Office_PK PRIMARY KEY (Office_ID));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE Faculty(
  2         Faculty_ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  3         First_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  4         Last_Name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  5         Office_ID INT NOT NULL,
  6              CONSTRAINT Faculty_PK PRIMARY KEY (Faculty_ID),  --> missing comma
  7              CONSTRAINT Faculty_FK FOREIGN KEY (Office_ID) REFERENCES Office(Office_ID));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE Student(
  2         Student_ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL ,
  3         First_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  4         Last_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  5         Phone_Number CHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  6         Sposue_Name VARCHAR (30),
  7         Street_Address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  8         City VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  9         State CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
 10         Zip VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
 11         Advisor_ID INT NOT NULL,
 12              CONSTRAINT Student_PK PRIMARY KEY (Student_ID),   --> missing comma
 13              CONSTRAINT Student_FK FOREIGN KEY (Advisor_ID) REFERENCES Faculty(Faculty_ID));

Table created.

SQL>
```